# How can I get typescript code coverage using karma and webpack in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, karma-runner, karma-coverage

I am using the webpack configuration that can be found in angular2 documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

If I add code coverage reporter, no lines/statement/functions are processed (zeros in generated report) although tests run as expected.